# Calling AAD Authenticated Azure function from Javascript without ADAL? No Access-control-allow-origin header is present

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, adal

Is it possible to call an AAD authenticated Azure function from javascript without an auth library like ADAL and also without registering the client application with Microsoft?

Getting this error:   **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin** '

Both the simple web client app and azure function are registered under the same AAD. Both have the azurewebsites.net domain.

What's the lightest web client we can have?

Comment: You can call without ADAL, but it's not possible without registering application on Azure AD

Comment: without any auth library? We've been trying with no luck, any samples you know of?

Comment: Not sure is there any sample on github, but it's just OpenID Connect, how have you tried?

Comment: We have both the client web app and functions app registered under the same AAD but get  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '  .

Comment: sorry, does OpenID imply i need to use a library like ADAL or MSAL?

Comment: Please try to use the implicit flow with response_type=token or response_type=id_token to get tokens directly from the authorize endpoint . Azure ad endpoints  don't support CORS .

Comment: @Nan Yu, sorry, can you elaborate some on where and how? Is this Azure specific or ADAL ? Do you think I must use ADAL ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is coming from a [cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) check. I suspect this occurs when calling the function from the web app. The idea is that the browser is making an OPTIONS request first to see if the caller (the web app) is allowed to make a call a resource on a different domain (the function app). If that's approved, then it will make the actual call to the function.

So, we just have to make it so that the function app responds letting the browser know the call is allowed. Fortunately, Functions has a built-in CORS feature. In the portal, select **Platform features** for your function app. Under the API section, you'll see a **CORS** option. Add the domain for your function app and click **Save**. You should see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error go away.

As for AAD, any OpenID Connect client library would work - ADAL is a fine choice for this, though. You may still need to create a client registration, though.

Comment: Thanks.  Cors is set, still failing.   side question,   ADAL requires client have server side code?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD ,with the normal OpenID Connect/OAuth flow, you would acquire token by making a request to the  `/token` endpoint. However, the azure ad endpoint does not support CORS requests, so making AJAX calls to get access tokens is out of the question. Instead, you can use [the implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant) in a hidden iframe to get new tokens for web APIs . See document [here](http://paulryan.com.au/2016/oauth-implicit-flow-js-without-adal-js/) and [here](https://platinumdogs.me/2016/04/19/grokking-the-azuread-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow/) for more details .

And yes,i would suggest you use ADAL.JS which helps you to use Azure AD for handling authentication easier .